How to make gallery columns responsive using Bootstrap Lightbox?
Want to be able to change the number of images (columns) in the Bootstrap-lightbox row from 3 in laptop view to 2 images in a tablet view.
The html template below has 3 images per row and adjusts to single column in mobile view. Is there a simple way using css or media queries, with bootstrap to change the number of images per row to two when in the small or medium bootstrap range?
So far I've only thought of creating a different lightbox html format for the tablet view (col-sm-6) by using a media query to switch to a "tablet size" html page. Wondering if there's a more efficient way to solve this. I want to avoid jquery and anything not beginner-friendly and stick to the current source thinking its possible to modify this with a media query or css.
The html works with bootstrap 5.3.3 and javascript source <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs5-lightbox@1.8.3/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
      <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=252" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=252" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
      <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=253" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=253" class="img-fluid">
      </a>

Simply adding another class .col-sm-6 to the images will not work for me because their position in the row just pushes the row into the next row leaving an open space.

You don't need to wrap every three columns into an individual row - you can stick them all into one row. And then using different columns classes for the different breakpoints should work fine.

Yeah, that seems like it will work fine. I will try it out, thanks!

Thanks, that totally worked for me, really appreciate your response.
